# CSS DIV Columns with varying heights

Tags: php, css, html

Ok so I've tried everything I can think of to get this working correctly, it's kind of a PHP/CSS question.

I have 12 DIV's of varying heights. What I'm trying to do is make two columns of 6, where the DIV's of the bottoms line up with the top...here's my example:

```
.testimonial-padding {
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

 <div class="testimonial-padding">
    <div class="sidebar_top">TITLE</div>
    <div class="sidebar_bottom">    <em>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin 
                eu erat iaculis orci varius vehicula. Nullam vehicula tellus sit 
                amet lacus hendrerit, eget malesuada erat faucibus. Sed id nulla 
                non elit ultrices faucibus. Praesent accumsan leo in sem ornare 
                suscipit ac sed odio. Praesent placerat pharetra laoreet. In auctor 
                auctor vulputate. Integer nec tortor et diam faucibus fringilla. 
                Cras sed mattis dolor, vel dictum orci. Etiam accumsan eu velit 
                vel suscipit. Nam auctor nisl at sapien vulputate vulputate. Sed 
                eget mi ut erat consequat convallis. Donec sit amet mattis erat, 
                non ullamcorper lorem. Praesent ac quam elementum, scelerisque dolor 
                sit amet, dapibus sapien. Fusce sit amet tortor aliquet, eleifend 
                risus et, dignissim eros. Nunc ultricies sem at euismod dignissim. 
                In urna nibh, aliquam nec ornare eu, gravida ac lorem. Proin tellus 
                enim, tincidunt eget tincidunt et, ultricies sed libero. Sed quis 
                justo sed metus tincidunt convallis sed in lacus. Aliquam pharetra 
                consectetur metus ut semper. Vestibulum non imperdiet dolor, non 
                rhoncus enim. Cras nec massa ac ligula iaculis porta. Pellentesque 
                habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac 
                turpis egestas. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis 
                in faucibus. Mauris nec turpis fermentum, blandit turpis eget, gravida 
                massa. Nullam eu posuere orci. Praesent viverra malesuada accumsan. 
                Phasellus semper eu nisi at luctus. Nullam dignissim sed nunc vitae 
                porttitor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus 
                et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur at sem vitae lacus 
                cursus varius. Duis blandit nisi commodo lacus volutpat, at eleifend 
                augue sodales. Nulla consectetur nunc nec imperdiet ultricies. Suspendisse 
                congue, eros non fringilla convallis, diam ante sodales ligula, 
                rhoncus mattis sem leo vel massa. Vivamus semper aliquet mi, ut 
                ultrices magna pellentesque et. Phasellus a ornare ipsum. Nullam 
                vel elit vitae nisi ullamcorper lobortis nec id purus. Cum sociis 
                natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus 
                mus. Sed vel leo eget turpis egestas cursus vel ac quam. Curabitur 
                vulputate ut nulla id consectetur. Pellentesque quis adipiscing 
                dui. Duis porttitor dignissim condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. 
                Aliquam ornare neque ut ipsum rutrum, in bibendum dolor mollis. 
                Aliquam quam tellus, egestas in massa vel, consectetur posuere lacus. 
                Curabitur pretium porta ultrices. Cras nulla orci, fermentum fermentum 
                libero vel, bibendum scelerisque odio. Duis tristique lorem quis 
                tempor hendrerit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque 
                malesuada, turpis sed accumsan vulputate, neque ante eleifend lorem, 
                a egestas purus elit vitae augue. Maecenas suscipit pellentesque 
                nunc vel lobortis. Vivamus a nisl volutpat, pulvinar quam in, malesuada 
                velit. Nam consequat consequat purus sit amet suscipit. In molestie 
                viverra mauris ut molestie. Proin consequat tincidunt sollicitudin. 
                Nam semper, lacus a aliquam interdum, sem quam suscipit ipsum, eu 
                ornare purus sem sit amet est. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante 
                ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla ac libero dolor. Aliquam dolor lacus, 
                consectetur vitae hendrerit at, suscipit a odio. Aliquam eget felis 
                ut ante fermentum aliquet. Phasellus vitae elit facilisis, pulvinar 
                felis ac, varius felis."</em>

        <br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="testimonial-padding">
    <div class="sidebar_top">TITLE</div>
    <div class="sidebar_bottom">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla condimentum magna eget porttitor dictum. Fusce at mi dui. Pellentesque ultrices velit ac risus pretium adipiscing. Donec commodo sodales ornare. Maecenas sollicitudin libero eu varius tristique. Sed laoreet tristique magna in ultrices. Sed rutrum nibh quis sem gravida, sed vulputate nibh aliquet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc non pulvinar erat, egestas mollis odio. Maecenas tortor risus, adipiscing sed libero ac, consequat varius felis. Nullam quis ante mauris. Etiam convallis congue dolor, et dapibus massa iaculis eu. Nulla ut arcu dui. Aenean mattis congue lacinia.
        <br>
        <br>Integer pretium convallis diam, vel volutpat tortor lobortis ut. Phasellus vel justo non felis posuere tristique sed vitae tellus. Duis nec urna in massa posuere posuere. Nullam risus nunc, rutrum ultricies placerat id, vehicula vel lacus. Praesent accumsan a lectus et consectetur. Sed ultrices nulla ut pulvinar rhoncus. Pellentesque at dapibus lorem. Cras libero augue, aliquam ac velit a, luctus ultricies urna. Nam nec massa consectetur, fringilla odio non, tempor enim. Donec eleifend lacinia odio, nec venenatis risus gravida vitae. Donec ut neque non sem convallis porttitor. Maecenas ultricies sollicitudin enim, commodo facilisis purus accumsan ac. Vivamus non ultrices leo.
        <br>
        <br>Vestibulum sit amet mollis neque. In tincidunt lacus quis consectetur auctor. Etiam at porta massa. Aenean ipsum nisl, mattis at enim eu, molestie vulputate arcu. Mauris feugiat urna vitae vulputate volutpat. Ut sagittis justo turpis, et bibendum risus volutpat quis. Phasellus sed ante semper, imperdiet purus vitae, fringilla arcu.</div>
</div>
<div class="testimonial-padding">
    <div class="sidebar_top">TITLE</div>
    <div class="sidebar_bottom">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla condimentum magna eget porttitor dictum. Fusce at mi dui. Pellentesque ultrices velit ac risus pretium adipiscing. Donec commodo sodales ornare. Maecenas sollicitudin libero eu varius tristique. Sed laoreet tristique magna in ultrices. Sed rutrum nibh quis sem gravida, sed vulputate nibh aliquet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc non pulvinar erat, egestas mollis odio. Maecenas tortor risus, adipiscing sed libero ac, consequat varius felis. Nullam quis ante mauris. Etiam convallis congue dolor, et dapibus massa iaculis eu. Nulla ut arcu dui. Aenean mattis congue lacinia.
        <br>
        <br>Integer pretium convallis diam, vel volutpat tortor lobortis ut. Phasellus vel justo non felis posuere tristique sed vitae tellus. Duis nec urna in massa posuere posuere. Nullam risus nunc, rutrum ultricies placerat id, vehicula vel lacus. Praesent accumsan a lectus et consectetur. Sed ultrices nulla ut pulvinar rhoncus. Pellentesque at dapibus lorem. Cras libero augue, aliquam ac velit a, luctus ultricies urna. Nam nec massa consectetur, fringilla odio non, tempor enim. Donec eleifend lacinia odio, nec venenatis risus gravida vitae. Donec ut neque non sem convallis porttitor. Maecenas ultricies sollicitudin enim, commodo facilisis purus accumsan ac. Vivamus non ultrices leo.
        <br>
        <br>Vestibulum sit amet mollis neque. In tincidunt lacus quis consectetur auctor. Etiam at porta massa. Aenean ipsum nisl, mattis at enim eu, molestie vulputate arcu. Mauris feugiat urna vitae vulputate volutpat. Ut sagittis justo turpis, et bibendum risus volutpat quis. Phasellus sed ante semper, imperdiet purus vitae, fringilla arcu.</div>
</div>
<div class="testimonial-padding">
    <div class="sidebar_top">TITLE</div>
    <div class="sidebar_bottom">    <em>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin 
                eu erat iaculis orci varius vehicula. Nullam vehicula tellus sit 
                amet lacus hendrerit, eget malesuada erat faucibus. Sed id nulla 
                non elit ultrices faucibus. Praesent accumsan leo in sem ornare 
                suscipit ac sed odio. Praesent placerat pharetra laoreet. In auctor 
                auctor vulputate. Integer nec tortor et diam faucibus fringilla. 
                Cras sed mattis dolor, vel dictum orci. Etiam accumsan eu velit 
                vel suscipit. Nam auctor nisl at sapien vulputate vulputate. Sed 
                eget mi ut erat consequat convallis. Donec sit amet mattis erat, 
                non ullamcorper lorem. Praesent ac quam elementum, scelerisque dolor 
                sit amet, dapibus sapien. Fusce sit amet tortor aliquet, eleifend 
                risus et, dignissim eros. Nunc ultricies sem at euismod dignissim. 
                In urna nibh, aliquam nec ornare eu, gravida ac lorem. Proin tellus 
                enim, tincidunt eget tincidunt et, ultricies sed libero. Sed quis 
                justo sed metus tincidunt convallis sed in lacus. Aliquam pharetra 
                consectetur metus ut semper. Vestibulum non imperdiet dolor, non 
                rhoncus enim. Cras nec massa ac ligula iaculis porta. Pellentesque 
                habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac 
                turpis egestas. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis 
                in faucibus. Mauris nec turpis fermentum, blandit turpis eget, gravida 
                massa. Nullam eu posuere orci. Praesent viverra malesuada accumsan. 
                Phasellus semper eu nisi at luctus. Nullam dignissim sed nunc vitae 
                porttitor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus 
                et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur at sem vitae lacus 
                cursus varius. Duis blandit nisi commodo lacus volutpat, at eleifend 
                augue sodales. Nulla consectetur nunc nec imperdiet ultricies. Suspendisse 
                congue, eros non fringilla convallis, diam ante sodales ligula, 
                rhoncus mattis sem leo vel massa. Vivamus semper aliquet mi, ut 
                ultrices magna pellentesque et. Phasellus a ornare ipsum. Nullam 
                vel elit vitae nisi ullamcorper lobortis nec id purus. Cum sociis 
                natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus 
                mus. Sed vel leo eget turpis egestas cursus vel ac quam. Curabitur 
                vulputate ut nulla id consectetur. Pellentesque quis adipiscing 
                dui. Duis porttitor dignissim condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. 
                Aliquam ornare neque ut ipsum rutrum, in bibendum dolor mollis. 
                Aliquam quam tellus, egestas in massa vel, consectetur posuere lacus. 
                Curabitur pretium porta ultrices. Cras nulla orci, fermentum fermentum 
                libero vel, bibendum scelerisque odio. Duis tristique lorem quis 
                tempor hendrerit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque 
                malesuada, turpis sed accumsan vulputate, neque ante eleifend lorem, 
                a egestas purus elit vitae augue. Maecenas suscipit pellentesque 
                nunc vel lobortis. Vivamus a nisl volutpat, pulvinar quam in, malesuada 
                velit. Nam consequat consequat purus sit amet suscipit. In molestie 
                viverra mauris ut molestie. Proin consequat tincidunt sollicitudin. 
                Nam semper, lacus a aliquam interdum, sem quam suscipit ipsum, eu 
                ornare purus sem sit amet est. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante 
                ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla ac libero dolor. Aliquam dolor lacus, 
                consectetur vitae hendrerit at, suscipit a odio. Aliquam eget felis 
                ut ante fermentum aliquet. Phasellus vitae elit facilisis, pulvinar 
                felis ac, varius felis."</em>
```

I've not added any styles to it, but if you put it in an editor, you'll see what i'm talking about. The bottom of the next doesn't line up with the top of the previous.

Anyone have any ideas on how this can be accomplished? I know there something that I'm missing with CSS on the "padder".

** UPDATE **

I have done research on this, searching Google and other search engines, I have not found anything that could resolve this issue, it's been ongoing for about 2 weeks now.

Comment: make a jsfiddle, so it is easier to understand...

Comment: I did and it didn't turn out right. Here's a link to a screenshot. Excuse the black lines, it's sensitive data. http://imgur.com/0AEvqne

Comment: actually, using 2 columns instead of rows of 2 columns, the only solution (I can think of) is to set a fixed height to each div and set overflow to hidden/scroll... otherwise is not possible cause there is not logic behind it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is probably not something most people would like to do but to do this most simply would be to make use of a table element.. since it will make all the rows align horizontally which is what i'm assuming you're trying to accomplish here if i understand correctly.

```
<table border="0">
    <tr style="vertical-align:top;">
        <td>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </td>
        <td>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />
        <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="vertical-align:top;">    
        <td>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </td>
        <td>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </th>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you Tony. A table is not really going to be possible because it's actually part of a mysql query that pulls information into each module, that's why they're varying heights. I've tried using this option and it just doesn't work.

Comment: @BradJTrammell really? you should be able to pull in a mysql query into any type of element. and if you mean that you have it pull the information in piece by piece and some won't show up sometimes you could use a foreach loop and increment an $i variable and with an if statement where if even numbers to open a table row (0) and odd numbers to close the table row and for the last one if it is even have a statement after the forloop with if ($i % 2 == 0) {//close table} and then end the </table>. anything is possible if you believe :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am m reading this right, but if what you are after is getting the text to line up with the top, rather then the bottom of the divs, then try adding the following to your testimonial padding class.

```
vertical-align:top;
```

If I misunderstood what your asking though, hit me back with a clarification.

Nate

Comment: Thank you Nate. I've actually tried using Vertical Align, and that doesn't seem to do anything. Here's a screen shot of what i'm dealing with right now.

http://imgur.com/0AEvqne

Sorry for the black lines, it's sensitive data.

Comment: Aha. think I'm starting to understand what your getting at. Try this method mate, I used it once recently. Url is. http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight.html. If you can't get it this way, give me all the code your using in the screenshot (without the text if it's sensitive) and I'll type it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

this should make u a starting point to solve your problem... use the divs as yours and follow the logic..

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andresmijares/Vq3Xq/)

```
  <section>
    <div class="col-1></div>
    <div class="col-2></div>
  </section>
```

repeat 3 times and keep it open to add more elements and close to modifications...

Comment: I believe that would be HTML5, which I can not use, most of the browsers that will be accessing this page do not support it.

Comment: use a div instead of the section tag... exactly the same ;0